Web3.py and WebSockets: ProviderConnectionError: Could not connect to: ... Retries exceeded
i use Python 3.12.0, web3 7.6.0 and Testnet (Sepolia) Infura
but i can't repeat the result described in the documentation
>>> import asyncio
>>> from web3 import Web3, AsyncWeb3

>>> WEB3_HTTP_URI = 'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<MY-API-KEY>'
>>> WEB3_WS_URI = 'wss://sepolia.infura.io/ws/v3/<MY-API-KEY>'


>>> w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(WEB3_HTTP_URI))
>>> w3.is_connected()  
True

for block above i got True (classic Web3 is used) but when i use AsyncWeb3 i always get false or errors:
>>> w3_async = AsyncWeb3(AsyncWeb3.AsyncHTTPProvider(WEB3_HTTP_URI))
>>> await w3_async.is_connected()
False

>>> w3_ws_async = await AsyncWeb3(AsyncWeb3.WebSocketProvider(WEB3_WS_URI))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vadim/PyProjects/fastWeb3/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/providers/persistent/persistent.py", line 101, in connect
    await self._provider_specific_connect()
  File "/Users/vadim/PyProjects/fastWeb3/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/providers/persistent/websocket.py", line 133, in _provider_specific_connect
    self._ws = await connect(self.endpoint_uri, **self.websocket_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vadim/PyProjects/fastWeb3/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 654, in __await_impl__
    _transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1126, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1159, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 575, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 557, in _do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 917, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 367, in runcode
    loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/vadim/PyProjects/fastWeb3/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/main.py", line 525, in __async_init__
    await self.provider.connect()
  File "/Users/vadim/PyProjects/fastWeb3/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/providers/persistent/persistent.py", line 114, in connect
    raise ProviderConnectionError(
web3.exceptions.ProviderConnectionError: Could not connect to: wss://sepolia.infura.io/ws/v3/<MY-API-KEY>. Retries exceeded max of 5.

UPD:



You need to remove the /ws from your WEB3_WS_URI.
Instead of wss://sepolia.infura.io/ws/v3/<MY-API-KEY>, it should be wss://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<MY-API-KEY>.
Like:
>>> WEB3_WS_URI = 'wss://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<MY-API-KEY>'

P.S. Also, make sure that you're launching the Python REPL (or Python CLI) using asyncio since you're using the awaited call in the line that you're executing.
python -m asyncio



that doesn't work in my case because path for WebSocketProvider connect is specified in the personal account and if i'm not mistaken it always looks like "wss://sepolia.infura.io/ws/v3/" ( see https://docs.metamask.io/services/get-started/endpoints/ ), and in any case it doesn't solve the problem of returning "False" for "await w3_async.is_connected()"

@Vadim, if you check the infura endpoints, they don’t have /ws in their urls. I’ve checked the same on my end, by removing /ws (i.e., before the /v3), it’s working completely fine.

The correct infura web-socket url for Sepolia testnet should be wss://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<YOUR_INFURA_API_KEY>.

may be, but i can't check it because in my case the problem is different, because nothing has changed from what was described in question

I've added one more thing in my answer that could possibly solve your problem. Please check.

I've also added my console screenshot, showing await w3_async.is_connected() returning True.

it's very strange why it doesn’t work for me.. yes, i imported asyncio lib from myself too (added this line to quetion)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
